# global var gives error "The variable ... is not defined." number -2753

Tags: scope, applescript

I have this code:

```
global logFilePath

Job("/Volumes/Work/test.log")

on Job(logFilePath)
  -- more code
  vlog("text")
  -- more code
end Job

on vlog(x)
   do shell script "echo \"" & (do shell script "date +' %H:%M:%S '") & x & "\" >> " & quoted form of logFilePath
end vlog
```

I keep getting `error "The variable logFilePath is not defined." number -2753 from "logFilePath"` from within the `on vlog` block.

Why? Haven't I declared it as global?

This works but is less elegant:

```
global logFilePath, logFilePath2

Job("/Volumes/Work/test.log")

on Job(logFilePath)
  set logFilePath2 to logFilePath
  -- more code
  vlog("text")
  -- more code
end Job

on vlog(x)
   do shell script "echo \"" & (do shell script "date +' %H:%M:%S '") & x & "\" >> " & quoted form of logFilePath2
end vlog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **local** variable `logFilePath` in the handler

```
 on Job(logFilePath)
```

is not the same object as the **global** variable with the same name, therefore it's indeed not defined.

---

To make it clear use a different name

```
global logFilePath

Job("/Volumes/Work/test.log")

on Job(localPath)
    set logFilePath to localPath
    -- more code
    vlog("text")
    -- more code
end Job

on vlog(x)
    do shell script "echo \"" & (do shell script "date +' %H:%M:%S '") & x & "\" >> " & quoted form of logFilePath
end vlog
```

---

Or only with local variables

```
Job("/Volumes/Work/test.log")

on Job(localPath)
    -- more code
    vlog("text", localPath)
    -- more code
end Job

on vlog(x, logFilePath)
    do shell script "echo \"" & (do shell script "date +' %H:%M:%S '") & x & "\" >> " & quoted form of logFilePath
end vlog
```